# Outlook Add-In generic publication for all regions

Tags: outlook-addin, manifest, office-addins, appsource

**We have multiple Add-In servers, lets say S1: in USA and S2: in Europe**

We want a single offer(one Manifest file) on AppSource when USA people installed an add-in static content should be served from **S1**, and for Europians **S2**

> With Manifest locale override:

This works when the Outlook language is updated. But a user in Europe uses a english language in outlook it send a request to USA server.

```
 <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://default_domain/taskpane.html">
      <Override Locale="es-es" Value="https://eu_server_domain/taskpane.html" />
      <Override Locale="en-us" Value="https://us_server_domain/taskpane.html" />      
 </SourceLocation>
```

**How we can write a single generic manifest, and submit it for publication. and end user can use it.
Some type solution while installation where users should be asked to install which version, USA-addin or Europe-addin.**

*Are we need to publish two different Add-In on AppSource?*